# Find R^2 after Using geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `geom_smooth(method = "nls", ...)` from `ggplot2` to fit my data, and I want to find the R-squared from the regression.

How can I recover the returned parameters from `nls`? Or is there a way to find the coefficient of determination directly?

Comment: https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/articles/user-guide.html#stat_poly_eq

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code example including sample data?

Comment: Just fit nls to the data directly